# Shows warning message in exported xlsx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel

My xlsx file is downloaded but when I open that xlsx file it shows warning as

> 'We found a problem with some content in'.

Can anyone tell me where I have to fix this?  I am using an iFrame to download the file.

```
using (ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
{
     wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Sheet1");
     Response.Clear();
     Response.Charset = "";
     Response.Buffer = true;
     Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
     Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
     Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + >Model.reportName + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHH:mm") + "." + extension);
     using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
     {
       wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
       MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
       Response.Flush();
       Response.Close();
       HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
     }
```

Comment: well you haven't told us anything about the content you're writing to the file, so it's a bit difficult to know.

Comment: I am getting the content as byte[] bytes = ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Render("EXCELOPENXML", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);

Comment: that still doesn't tell us what's actually in it